# Nginx returns 400 Bad request with diff versions

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am facing an issue in our systems with the following problem.

I have 2 VM's with Nginx 1.18.0 (ubuntu) installed.

One of our API requests seems to fail in one VM with 400 bad requests. The same request gets through other VM without any problem.

I tried checking further and I could see, that the successful response VM returns server version as 1.25.2 (But I could see the libs installed are indicating 1.18 ...PFB my details)

Failure Response Scenario:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9190/jflasjfl/asfjlaj/0/a1/%7B%asfd%sf%skfjaklj%2C%sjflkajf%22%3A1%2C%22noOfApply%22%3A0%2C%ksjfklj%22%3A0%2C%skfjaklj%22%3A0%2C%askjflj%22%3A0%2C%22indeedApply%22%3A0%2C%asjflaj%22%3A0%2C%aksjfkjla%22%3A0%2C%22shineView%22%3A0%2C%ksjfkja%22%3A0%2C%22facebookView%22%3A0%2C%aksjfkaj%22%3A0%2C%skafjkla%22%3A0%2C%alsfjkasj%22%3A0%2C%aksjfklaj%22%3A0%2C%asklfjlakj%22%3A0%2C%22monsterView%22%3A0%2C%askfjlkas%22%3A0%2C%22naukriView%22%3A0%2C%22naukriApply%22%3A0%2C%22timesJobView%22%3A0%2C%kasjflkaj%22%3A0%2C%22facebookTabView%22%3A0%2C%askjfkal%22%3A0%2C%alksjfklaj%22%3A0%2C%22linkedInShareApply%22%3A0%2C%askjfklsaj%22%3A0%2C%22googlePlusApply%22%3A0%2C%22careerSiteView%22%3A0%2C%akjsfklaj%22%3A0%2C%askfjklaj%22%3A0%2C%22quikrApply%22%3A0%2C%22otherView%22%3A0%2C%askjflak%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterUploadView%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterUploadApply%22%3A0%2C%22dailyHuntView%22%3A0%2C%22dailyHuntApply%22%3A0%2C%22simplyHiredView%22%3A0%2C%22simplyHiredApply%22%3A0%2C%22emailInviteView%22%3A1%2C%22emailInviteApply%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterShareView%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterShareApply%22%3A0%2C%22careerBuilderView%22%3A0%2C%22careerBuilderApply%22%3A0%2C%22jobRapidoView%22%3A0%2C%22jobRapidoApply%22%3A0%2C%22liveCareerView%22%3A0%2C%22liveCareerApply%22%3A0%2C%jaskljalkf%22%3A0%2C%akjfklaj%22%3A0%2C%22employeeReferralView%22%3A0%2C%22employeeReferralApply%22%3A0%2C%22referralInviteView%22%3A0%2C%kasjflkajkl%22%3A0%2C%22whatsappView%22%3A0%2C%22whatsappApply%22%3A0%2C%22vendorView%22%3A0%2C%22vendorApply%22%3A0%2C%kasjflkjal%22%3A0%2C%aksjflka%22%3A0%2C%22logDate%22%3A1702060200000%2C%22jobId%22%3A156792%2C%jfadlskjflka%22%3A0%2C%aslfjklajf%22%3A1%7D'
> Host: localhost:9190
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2023 05:07:24 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 435
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Language: en
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1></body></html
```

Successfull scenario:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9190/jflasjfl/asfjlaj/0/a1/%7B%asfd%sf%skfjaklj%2C%sjflkajf%22%3A1%2C%22noOfApply%22%3A0%2C%ksjfklj%22%3A0%2C%skfjaklj%22%3A0%2C%askjflj%22%3A0%2C%22indeedApply%22%3A0%2C%asjflaj%22%3A0%2C%aksjfkjla%22%3A0%2C%22shineView%22%3A0%2C%ksjfkja%22%3A0%2C%22facebookView%22%3A0%2C%aksjfkaj%22%3A0%2C%skafjkla%22%3A0%2C%alsfjkasj%22%3A0%2C%aksjfklaj%22%3A0%2C%asklfjlakj%22%3A0%2C%22monsterView%22%3A0%2C%askfjlkas%22%3A0%2C%22naukriView%22%3A0%2C%22naukriApply%22%3A0%2C%22timesJobView%22%3A0%2C%kasjflkaj%22%3A0%2C%22facebookTabView%22%3A0%2C%askjfkal%22%3A0%2C%alksjfklaj%22%3A0%2C%22linkedInShareApply%22%3A0%2C%askjfklsaj%22%3A0%2C%22googlePlusApply%22%3A0%2C%22careerSiteView%22%3A0%2C%akjsfklaj%22%3A0%2C%askfjklaj%22%3A0%2C%22quikrApply%22%3A0%2C%22otherView%22%3A0%2C%askjflak%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterUploadView%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterUploadApply%22%3A0%2C%22dailyHuntView%22%3A0%2C%22dailyHuntApply%22%3A0%2C%22simplyHiredView%22%3A0%2C%22simplyHiredApply%22%3A0%2C%22emailInviteView%22%3A1%2C%22emailInviteApply%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterShareView%22%3A0%2C%22recruiterShareApply%22%3A0%2C%22careerBuilderView%22%3A0%2C%22careerBuilderApply%22%3A0%2C%22jobRapidoView%22%3A0%2C%22jobRapidoApply%22%3A0%2C%22liveCareerView%22%3A0%2C%22liveCareerApply%22%3A0%2C%jaskljalkf%22%3A0%2C%akjfklaj%22%3A0%2C%22employeeReferralView%22%3A0%2C%22employeeReferralApply%22%3A0%2C%22referralInviteView%22%3A0%2C%kasjflkajkl%22%3A0%2C%22whatsappView%22%3A0%2C%22whatsappApply%22%3A0%2C%22vendorView%22%3A0%2C%22vendorApply%22%3A0%2C%kasjflkjal%22%3A0%2C%aksjflka%22%3A0%2C%22logDate%22%3A1702060200000%2C%22jobId%22%3A156792%2C%jfadlskjflka%22%3A0%2C%aslfjklajf%22%3A1%7D'
> Host: localhost:9190
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Server: nginx/1.25.2
< Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2023 05:06:11 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, authorization, x-csrftoken,x-xsrf-token
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
```

here is the output of nginx installed details on those servers:
VM1 (Failure scenario)

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

VM1 (Successfull scenario)

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Not sure where i am missing but its bit confusing. Please help

Comment: Found the problem myself. Thanks Anyway.

Once we upgrade the nginx to 1.24. it got solved.